# Execute shell script using cygiwn through chef

Tags: cygwin, chef-infra

I can't find anyway to execute a shell script inside cygwin using chef in windows is there anyway to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `script` resource and set the `interpreter` attribute to `bash`. Just make sure that the command `bash` is on your PATH.

```
script "test_module" do
  interpreter "bash"
  code <<-EOH
  echo 'Starting the script...'
  cp C:/Temp/testfile.txt C:/Temp/testfile2.txt 
EOH
end
```

This was tested on Windows 10.

Comment: if i have to start it in background other chef will wait for this to finish ?

Comment: Once you stat a background process the foreground will continue onward. You will need another way to synchronize.